# CSV.write() won't take nothing values

Tags: julia

I'm trying to export a Julia dataframe into a CSV and it contains nothing values. To simiplify let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
using DataFrames, CSV

df = DataFrame(A = [nothing,2,3], B = [4,5,nothing])
```

When I try to export, I get the following error:

```
df |> CSV.write("df.csv")

ArgumentError: `nothing` should not be printed; use `show`, `repr`, or custom output instead.
```

Should I convert the nothing values to something else like missing? If so, how would I code this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `something` function to convert `nothing` to whatever you want (e.g. `missing`) like this:

```
something.(df, missing) |> CSV.write("aaa.txt")
```

The current reasoning behind the design not to support `nothing` when writing a CSV file is given [here](https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl/issues/433#issuecomment-509906252).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the syntax of the CSV `transform` argument:

```
CSV.write("filename.csv", df, transform=(col, val) -> something(val, missing))
```

[From the CSV.write documentation](https://juliadata.github.io/CSV.jl/stable/#CSV.write)

Posting this as a separate answer, hopefully to distinguish comments and gather clarifications if I am missing something important.